# Retrieveing data from document of a collection in firestore database with document ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a chat application with chat room by implementing firebase friendly chat app. I want to get all the information from "rooma" documentid of message collection. But i am not able to get the information from the document with ID "rooma" but i can access all the information from "message" collection.
my code is:

```
function loadMessages() {
  // Create the query to load the last 12 messages and listen for new ones.
  var query = firebase.firestore()
                  .collection('messages').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'rooma').get()
                  .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                  .limit(12);

  // Start listening to the query.
  query.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        deleteMessage(change.doc.id);
      } else {
        var message = change.doc.data();
        displayMessage(change.doc.id, message.timestamp, message.name,
                       message.text, message.profilePicUrl, message.imageUrl);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

my database structure is:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9wrC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data of "the document with `ID` 'rooma'", just do as follows, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=0#get_a_document):

```
var docRef = db.collection("messages").doc("rooma");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

If you want to use `onSnapshot()`, in order to "*listen* to a document", you just have to do as follows, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen):

```
var docRef = db.collection("messages").doc("rooma");
docRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
     console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Comment: then how will I customize the onSnapshot() function??

Comment: i want to make a query and a onSnapshot at same time

Comment: A query on what exactly? It is not 100% clear in you question.